# Decrypt Encrypted Files Using Key Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption

I have some files encrypted using BitLocker how ever I think I have formatted my PC without decrypting them. now my HDD doesn't show it has turned on BitLocker. but those files are encrypted and can't decrypt now. I have the key

The error that comes when I decrypt here:

[image: Error]

I have tried giving permission also but didn't work

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your images are inaccessible. Use the Upload Image capability of the editor to share your images.

Comment: @Ramhound: I can access them ok.

Comment: @harrymc - The image host is blocked and I cannot view the images.

Comment: What type of key do you have? Is it a .pfx file or a .bek file or just numbers?

Comment: @user1686 it's just numbers. i have backup it on google drive

Comment: I have the feeling that the files are lost. I hope you have backups.

Comment: Without the certificate that encrypted the files, it will NOT be possible, to decrypt the files in question.

Answer (score 2):

The files you are trying to access are not encrypted using BitLocker, but rather using the NTFS feature [Encrypted File System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-encryption) (EFS). It is not related to BitLocker at all.

Unless you still have access to a full-disk backup of the previous Windows installation (including your user profile), decrypting the files is no longer possible. The EFS encryption key is stored inside the Windows user profile and tied to the account password.

Theoretically, the EFS key can also be backed up. However, prompts to do so are not very prominent, so it is unlikely you have a backup. The backup would be a `*.pfx` file.